# XGBoost4J - Scala dataframe to sparse dmatrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, sparse-matrix, databricks, xgboost

What is the most efficient and scalable way to convert a scala dataframe to a sparse dmatrix for XGBoost4J?

Say I have a dataframe `train` with columns `row_index`, `column_index`, and `value`, it would be something like

```
new DMatrix(train.select("row_index"), train.select("column_index"), train.select("Value"), DMatrix.SparseType.CSR, n_col)
```

However the above code results in a type mismatch because DMatrix expects `Array[Long]`.

`train.select(F.collect_list("row_index")).first().getList[Long](0)` seems like a possible option but it doesn't seem to be memory friendly and scalable.

I am doing this on Databricks so solutions in the other supported languages (python, SQL, scala) are welcome.

Comment: have you looked into docs: https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/train-model/xgboost.html ?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes I have. All of the examples use data in wide format. My data is in long format, and since it's highly sparse, I'm trying to avoid pivoting to wide format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use sparse vectors by row rather than trying to create sparse matrix or dmatrix.

`train.rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(0), (r.getInt(1), r.getInt(2).toDouble))).groupByKey().map(r => (r._1, Vectors.sparse(n_col, r._2.toSeq))).toDF`

I tested scoring a sample of the data in `R` using `Matrix::sparseMatrix` and `xgboost::dmatrix` and the results matched up.